# Flutter Boxfit.cover image with slider animation

Tags: flutter, image, dart, animation

I have a Flutter project with a `PageView` with different Images, that fill the entire screen with the `BoxFit.cover` property. What I want to achieve is an automatically initial animation, that begins with setting the Image Widget property alignment to `Alignment.centerLeft` and then animates the image to `Alignment.centerRight`, e.g. the images moves from left to right, and then, as soon as the image reaches the `Alignment.centerLeft` final position, it automatically switches to the next `PageView`.

I tried wrapping the `Image` Widget with the `AnimatedAlign`, but then the `Boxfit.cover` does not work anymore.

I want an animation like this:

[image]

```dart
PageView(
  children: [
    Container(
      child: Image(
        // Here I want the animation to go from 
        // Alignment.centerLeft to Alignment.centerRight 
        // and then automatically switch to the next PageView
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft 
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: AssetImage("assets/image1.jpg"),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Image(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: AssetImage("assets/image2.jpg"),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Image(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: AssetImage("assets/image3.jpg"),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```